# A “universal” binary?

Tags: elf, portable-executable, mach-o

Is there a way to combine ELF, Mach-O and PE compiled code in the general case, so there could be one “binary” file for all modern systems? (Windows, macOS, Linux)

I remember there are stories of old game developers who hand-arranged the bytes of games on floppy disks so they worked on both Amstrad and Amiga devices — I’m wondering if the same could be done for, say, a trivial Go application that has been compiled for each of the modern operating systems (and potentially intel & ARM)

I know Mach-O executables for intel & ARM can be combined into “universal” binaries, which allows the one executable to work on both architectures (by placing both executables in one file), and I can see [PE and ELF both support “fat binaries”](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_executable_file_formats) — could something similar be possible cross-platform?

Comment: Would a `.zip` file containing individual binaries (plus a shell script to choose the correct one to execute) count?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner what shell is on all those platforms by default?

Comment: Not without changing the operating systems.  The Windows kernel doesn't know how to load an ELF, and the Linux kernel doesn't know how to load a PE.

Comment: There isn't a way to merge the format headers such that they're interpreted in the right way on the different OS. One of the hurdles is the magic number that's placed at the beginning of the file, which differs between the two formats.

Comment: It isn't possible to combine the existing executable formats. Because each format has its own specific needs to be run by their each respective OSes. But it is theoretically possible for OS vendors to design a common executable format that they should/can adopt it.

Comment: @starball maybe someday bash, but for now you'd have the challenge of writing a launcher script that is both a valid .bat (or PowerShell) script and also a valid bash script.  That's somewhere between difficult and impossible as well, but I suspect it would be much easier than trying to craft a cross-OS executable (at least without first getting explicit support from the OS manufacturers for it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on whether you're willing to loosen your definition of "binary" or not.

If you want a binary that can be loaded directly by the respective kernels, with no shell or other kind of interpreter present, then this is not possible. This is due to the simple fact that PE, ELF and Mach-O have strict requirements for the first few bytes of the file, which are mutually exclusive:

- PE files must begin with bytes `4D 5A`.
- ELF files must begin with bytes `7F 45 4C 46`.
- Mach-O files must begin with:

  - `FE ED FA CE` (32-bit, big endian)
  - `FE ED FA CF` (64-bit, big endian)
  - `CE FA ED FE` (32-bit, little endian)
  - `CF FA ED FE` (64-bit, little endian)
  - `CA FE BA BE` (fat, big endian)
  - `BE BA FE CA` (fat, little endian)

You should be able to create a polyglot that is both a fat Mach-O and a Java class file (I briefly looked into this some time ago, and I think the Java class file format should allow you to encode as much of the Mach-O header in the constant pool, unused).
You can also create a polyglot of any of the above that is also a [dmg file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Disk_Image), since those have the "header" at the end of the file (this is how "pkgdmg" works, some files shipped by Apple are both valid pkg/xar files as well as valid dmgs).
But you cannot stuff any two of PE, ELF and Mach-O into the same binary file header.

But if you're willing to make use of a shell, then this is very doable. And it has been done, by Justine Tunney: [Actually Portable Executable](https://justine.lol/ape.html). Quoting the beginning of that blog post:

> One day, while studying old code, I found out that it's possible to encode Windows Portable Executable files as a UNIX Sixth Edition shell script, due to the fact that the Thompson Shell didn't use a shebang line. Once I realized it's possible to create a synthesis of the binary formats being used by Unix, Windows, and MacOS, I couldn't resist the temptation of making it a reality, since it means that high-performance native code can be almost as pain-free as web apps. Here's how it works:
>
> ```
> MZqFpD='
> BIOS BOOT SECTOR'
> exec 7<> $(command -v $0)
> printf '\177ELF...LINKER-ENCODED-FREEBSD-HEADER' >&7
> exec "$0" "$@"
> exec qemu-x86_64 "$0" "$@"
> exit 1
> REAL MODE...
> ELF SEGMENTS...
> OPENBSD NOTE...
> NETBSD NOTE...
> MACHO HEADERS...
> CODE AND DATA...
> ZIP DIRECTORY...
> ```

Such a file will run natively on Windows, and on other OSes it will launch as a shell script, which can then detect the host environment to extract and run the correct embedded binary.
But because it is a shell script (without a shebang line), it will only work from a shell, not if invoked directly with a syscall such as `execve()`. This would not be the case *with* a shebang line, but then you just transform the problem into making a polyglot of a (ba)sh script and something else.

Comment: This is fascinating and exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much  I'm definitely going to play with this, and see what I can do!